# Using php inside .js files and perfomance

Tags: javascript, php, performance, .htaccess

I just realised (after a few years) that [its posible](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-htaccess-snippets-to-optimize-your-website) to use PHP in .js files an that sounds pretty handy (specially when serving, for example, language texts from the database)

just like this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js

<FilesMatch "\.(js|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

So my questions is, how much Does this affect perfomance? I guess its not considered a static file anymore and it won't be cached same way?

-EDIT-

Note: I am already using cache-control to the .js files via htaccess

Comment: I can't answer your question about the performance but I can tell you that's not a good practice ... you can output whatever you want let say in JSON format from your PHP script, and then access it via your JS file ...

Comment: Hi @Mahdi that's what I am currently Doing.. that's why I asked about perfomance ;)

Comment: How much this affect performance depends on the size of the JS file, the speed of the processing server and so many other variables; as asked this is unanswerable.

Comment: Well I guess that if it's cached same way or not Does have an answer ;) @iambriansreed

Comment: Fine, I will vote to close it, too.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet, Toni, do you want the browser caches your files or not? If yes, then how would you make sure that all the users would get the recent and updated JS file? I think it's not about performance unless you don't let the browsers cache your files, and if you let them cache, then it's not a good practice because some users might not get the updated version of JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web browser won't be able to see if it's coming from PHP or not, however you can manually set custom HTTP headers like `Cache-Control`, `Expires` or `Last-Modified` in a way that browsers cache your dynamic Javascript files, but it then defeats the purpose of making them dynamic unless you make sure that these Javascript files won't be updated in a period of time (let say a day for example) and then set the proper headers to control the browser cache.

As I said in the comments it's not a good practice for three reasons:

1. Overhead for processing Javascript files via PHP -- performance issue.
2. You have to shutdown the caching mechanism in the client's web browser, so they will be able to get the latest and updated version of your Javascript files -- performance issue again.
3. If you let the web browser caches the file, then some users won't get the latest Javascript file -- or in other words, it's not dynamic anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Affects performance as from now on browsers won't be able to cache javascript files. Make your javascript files to deal with data coming from remote sources.

What I usually tend to do is the following:

In your view (php), you define a config javascript object:

```
var CompanyNS.modules.whatever.config = {
    id: <?php echo $object->getId(); ?>,
    name: <?php echo $object->getName(); ?>
}
```

And in your javascript:

```
var config = CompanyNS.modules.whatever.config;
// do whatever you need with the dynamic data
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer; that's pretty much what I am doing so far, I kind of imagined that it won't be such a good plan but its allways welcome some second thoughts